# NE555 Delay On Off Timer Schematic

Tags: led, 555, timer, delay, monostable

I'm trying to make a timer that turns on at a certain time and turns off after 3 seconds, i found a circuit in youtube and made it in proteus, but the output is not the same.

Is there a problem with my schematic??
[image]

Comment: How does the output differ? Is it a problrm if it is different? What output you were expecting?

Comment: try 44 uf capacitor for C2

Answer (score 3):

Your time constant is way too long for a 3 second delay. Refer to the NE555 [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/NE555_SA555_NA555.pdf). The time should be about 1.1 RC, which you have at about 38 seconds, more than 10x too long. So reduce C2 (preferably) and/or R3.

Also, the switch needs to be momentary normally open and released before the end of the time period. If you can't do that, you'll need  to add an RC to the trigger input.